# Python Regular Expressions to NFA

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am currently using python's `re` module to search and capture groups.
I've list of regular expressions which I have to compile and match against a **large dataset** which causes performance issues.

`Example:`

```
REGEXES = [
    '^New York(?P<grp1>\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$',
    '^Ohio (?P<grp1>\d+/\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$',
    '(?P<year>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})$',
    '^(?P<year>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})$',
    '^(?P<title>.+?)[- ]+E(?P<epi>\d+)$'
    .
    .
    .
    .
]
```

*Note*: Regexes won't be similar

```
COMPILED_REGEXES = [re.compile(r, flags=re.I) for r in REGEXES]

def find_match(string):
    for regex in COMPILED_REGEXES:
        match = regex.search(string)
        if not match:
            continue
        return match
```

Is there a way around this? The idea is to avoid iteration through the compiled regexes to get a match.

Comment: Have you tried one large regex instead? You can create named capture groups and concatenate them together with `|`.

Comment: I will try it out and see if it improves the performance. If we talk about NFA I am not sure if we can mimic the way we capture groups using `re`

Comment: @rumpelsepp I tried one large regex but ran into few issues with python `re` as it doesn't support duplicate group names and has a limit for capturing groups. I ended up using   another module `regex` which doesn't have these restrictions.
I am not sure if there are any major difference between how `re` works and how `regex `works internally.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I saw David Beazley do a trick that might be useful to you. He combined the separate regexes, putting each in a named group, and then used the undocumented `scanner` function to handle each match separately. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1twn9kLmYg .

The only problem is that you also use named groups--perhaps you could have a two-step approach, first match the overall patern, than break each match into the parts you want. Or have a separate mapping from groups to names.

Comment: BTW, you should use raw strings for proper interpretation of escape characters? E.g. `r'^New York(?P<grp1>\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$'`

Comment: Is it the number of regexes or the size of the dataset where the performance bottle neck occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do any of your regexps break DFA compatibility? Doesn't look like it in your examples. You can use a [Python wrapper](https://pypi.org/project/re2/) around a C/C++ DFA implementation like [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/), which is a drop in replacement for `re`. `re2` will also fall back to using `re` if the regex is incompatible with the `re2` [syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax), so it will optimize all possible cases, and not fail on incompatible cases.

Note that `re2` **does** support the `(?P<name>regex)` capture syntax, but it **doesn't** support the `(?P=<name>)` backref sytnax.

```
try:
    import re2 as re
    re.set_fallback_notification(re.FALLBACK_WARNING)
except ImportError:
    # latest version was for Python 2.6
else:
    import re
```

If you have regexps with backrefs, you can still use `re2` with a few special considerations: you'll need to replace the backrefs in your regexps with `.*?`, and you may find false matches which you can filter out with `re`. In real world data, the false matches will probably be uncommon.

Here is an illustrative example:

```
import re
try:
    import re2
    re2.set_fallback_notification(re2.FALLBACK_WARNING)
except ImportError:
    # latest version was for Python 2.6

REGEXES = [
    '^New York(?P<grp1>\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$',
    '^Ohio (?P<grp1>\d+/\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$',
    '(?P<year>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})$',
    '^(?P<year>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})$',
    '^(?P<title>.+?)[- ]+E(?P<epi>\d+)$',
]

COMPILED_REGEXES = [re.compile(r, flags=re.I) for r in REGEXES]
# replace all backrefs with .*? for re2 compatibility
# is there other unsupported syntax in REGEXES?
COMPILED_REGEXES_DFA = [re2.compile(re2.sub(r'\\d|\\g\\d|\\g\<\d+\>|\\g\<\w+\>', '.*?', r), flags=re2.I) for r in REGEXES]

def find_match(string):
    for regex, regex_dfa in zip(COMPILED_REGEXES, COMPILED_REGEXES_DFA):
        match_dfa = regex_dfa.search(string)
        if not match_dfa:
            continue
        match = regex.search(string)
        # most likely branch comes first for better branch prediction
        if match:
            return match
```

If this isn't fast enough, you can employ a variety of techniques to feed the DFA hits to `re` as they are processed, instead of storing them in a file or in memory and handing them off once they're all collected.

You can also combine all your regexps into one big DFA regexp of alternating groups `(r1)|(r2)|(r3)| ... |(rN)` and iterate through your group matches on the resulting match object to try to match only the corresponding original regexps. The match result object will have the same state as with OP's original solution.

```
# rename group names in regexeps to avoid name collisions
REGEXES_PREFIXED = [re2.sub(r'\(\?P\<(\w+)\>', r'(P<re{}_\1>'.format(idx), r) for idx, r in enumerate(REGEXES)]
# wrap and fold regexps (?P<hit0>pattern)| ... |(?P<hitN>pattern)
REGEX_BIG = ''
for idx, r in enumerate(REGEXES_PREFIXED):
    REGEX_BIG += '(?P<hit{}>{})|'.format(idx, r)
else:
    REGEX_BIG = REGEX_BIG[0:-1]
regex_dfa_big = re2.compile(REGEX_BIG, flags = re2.I)

def find_match(string):
    match_dfa = regex_dfa_big.search(string)
    if match_dfa:
        # only interested in hit# match groups
        hits = [n for n, _ in match_dfa.groupdict().iteritems() if re2.match(r'hit\d+', n)]
        # check for false positives
        for idx in [int(h.replace('hit', '')) for h in hits]
            match = COMPILED_REGEXES[idx].search(string)
            if match:
                return match
```

You can also look at [pyre](https://github.com/facebook/pyre2/) which is a better maintained wrapper for the same C++ library, but not a drop in replacement for `re`. There's also a [Python Wrapper](https://github.com/davidblewett/rure-python) for [RuRe](https://github.com/rust-lang/regex), which is the fastest regex engine I know of.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate my comment: the problem with putting it all in one big regexp is that group names must be unique. However, you could process your regexes as follows:

```
import re

REGEXES = [
    r'^New York(?P<grp1>\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$',
    r'^Ohio (?P<grp1>\d+/\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$',
    r'(?P<year>\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})$',
    r'^(?P<year>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})$',
    r'^(?P<title>.+?)[- ]+E(?P<epi>\d+)$']

# Find the names of groups in the regexps
groupnames = {'RE_%s'%i:re.findall(r'\(\?P<([^>]+)>', r) for i, r in enumerate(REGEXES)}

# Convert the named groups into unnamed ones
re_list_cleaned = [re.sub(r'\?P<([^>]+)>', '', r) for r in REGEXES]

# Wrap each regexp in a named group
token_re_list = ['(?P<RE_%s>%s)'%(i, r) for i, r in enumerate(re_list_cleaned)]

# Put them all together
mighty_re = re.compile('|'.join(token_re_list), re.MULTILINE)

# Use the regexp to process a big file
with open('bigfile.txt') as f:
    txt = f.read()
for match in mighty_re.finditer(txt):
    # Now find out which regexp made the match and put the matched data in a dictionary
    re_name = match.lastgroup
    groups = [g for g in match.groups() if g is not None]
    gn = groupnames[re_name]
    matchdict = dict(zip(gn, groups[1:]))
    print ('Found:', re_name, matchdict)
```

Comment: I read your code more carefully. It's a little unorthodox but makes sense. The small problem remains that you invalidated match.groupdict(), and OP might be using that in his code elsewhere. I realize that matchdict is identical. Maybe you can update the internals of match so that OP doesn't have to alter his code in any way to use your solution. It seems like a distant concern to strip all group names to make sure the ones that you wrap with are unique, but it's simple enough as long as you can recreate the match object's would-be state.

Comment: I see. You need to strip all the group names because the group names collide when concatenating the regexps together.

Comment: Exactly! grp1, grp2, year etc were used in multiple regexps, causing the problems. As an alternative, you could prefix the group names instead of stripping them, there are lots of options to improve the code.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest do following steps:

1. Create an excel called Patterns.csv and have two columns in it **Patterns** & **Name** where pattern is the regex pattern like `^New York(?P<grp1>\d+/\d+): (?P<grp2>.+)$'` and name can be `New York`. This will help you in maintaining all the regex in a separate resource other than your code. It will help you in future if you want to add/subtract/modify regexes.
2. Read that csv using below command:

   `import pandas as pd

   df = pd.read_csv("\\Patterns.csv")`
3. Write code to parse this csv as below:

   `pattern = df['pattern'].tolist()
   pattern_name = df['name'].tolist()
   pattern_dict = dict(zip(pattern_name, pattern))`
4. Write a pattern regex to find out all the values that are matching:

`import collections
sep =  " ;; "
NLU_Dict=collections.defaultdict()
for pn, p in pattern_dict.items():
    val = sep.join([sep.join(filter(lambda x: len(str(x).strip()) >0, map(str, v))) for in re.findall(p, text, re.I)])
    NLU_Dict[pn] = val`

Your `NLU_Dict` will be a dict. separated by `;;` containing values of pattern names which are matched and blank for what it not matched.

Comment: PLEASE don't use pandas to read in a CSV.  That is a freaking 25mb wheel.  Just use damn `import csv`.  My god the waste.

Comment: @Julian: Do read https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/fastest-python-library-to-read-a-csv-file to let know what is the fastest way to read csv to python. And here OP wants something which is fast and efficient

Comment: Look, pandas IS faster at parsing data from a CSV, but it's like .15 seconds faster for a dataset of like 20,000 rows.  Since this is only being done ONCE, I would argue the bigger waste is the huge library you are pulling in.  IE overkill.  The issues OP is having aren't coming from the importing or even looping over the REGEXES list, it's the large dataset comparisons that are the problem.

Comment: We can agree to disagree but i dont think this is the right question or space to do so

Answer (score 0):

I would look at `re.Scanner`. It is undocumented and flagged as experimental, but is a good example of using `sre_parse` and `sre_compile` to build a regex by parsing, merging, then compiling.  If you don't care for group names, and only want to capture groups, this should work.  Mind you, this code has no error checking.

```
import re
import sre_parse
import sre_compile


def compile_multiple(subpatterns, flags=0):
    """
    Return a compiled regex from an iterable collection of
    pattern strings so that it matches any of the patterns
    in the collection.
    """
    from sre_constants import BRANCH, SUBPATTERN
    if isinstance(flags, re.RegexFlag):
        flags = flags.value
    pattern = sre_parse.Pattern()
    pattern.flags = flags
    parsed_subpatterns = []
    for subpattern in subpatterns:
        gid = pattern.opengroup()
        parsed_subpattern = sre_parse.parse(subpattern, flags)
        parsed_subpatterns.append(sre_parse.SubPattern(pattern, [
            (SUBPATTERN, (gid, 0, 0, sre_parse.parse(subpattern, flags))),
        ]))
        pattern.closegroup(gid, parsed_subpatterns[-1])
    combined_pattern = sre_parse.SubPattern(pattern, [(BRANCH, (None, parsed_subpatterns))])
    return sre_compile.compile(combined_pattern)
```

Answer (score -1):

If all of your regex patterns follow the same format of a city name (not captured) followed by a captured series of `/`-delimited numbers, a colon and a space, and then a captured rest of the string, you can simply parse them all with the same regex pattern of:

```
def find_match(string):
    return re.search(r'(?P<grp1>\d+(?:/\d+)*): (?P<grp2>.+)', string)
```

Comment: That's the pain because the regexes are different pattern :/

Comment: Can you update your question with more of the distinctly different regex patterns? The two examples you gave are rather similar.

Comment: I have added few more regexes in my question above